# Is there any way to find previous sibling in Coded UI

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have a Control which is first children of the Parent but nothing is unique in Parent and in the Control. I can find unique properties for Scond children so I need to find the previous Sibling of Second children

Comment: is this web, wpf, windows or windows store app? depending on the type of application you can search for siblings. do you have more information on the application you try to test? screenshot, triggering code?

Comment: It is a Desktop application and I am using CodedUI to automate

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using the SearchConfiguration property on the control.
What you do is you search for the label and next you instantiate a WinEdit control and pass it in the label search control. Next you set on the WinEdit instance the SearchConfiguration.Add(SearchConfiguration.NextSibling)
this will now search for the next sibling of the text label.
in a code example this looks like follows:

```
 var app = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"yourapplication.exe");
 var mainWindow = new WinWindow(app);
 mainWindow.WindowTitles.Add("Form1");

 WinText textLabel = new WinText(mainWindow);
 textLabel.SearchProperties.Add(WinControl.PropertyNames.Name, "Some Text Label");

 WinEdit siblingEditControl = new WinEdit(textLabel);
 siblingEditControl.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.NextSibling);
 siblingEditControl.Text = "setting the text";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct methods for getting siblings. One way of finding the siblings of a control is to find its parent and then find all the children of that parent. Next search through the children to find the current control and then take the previous one. The method might be based on the following. It uses the `Name` fields of the control for the comparison, this may be incorrect for the general case and I suggest other values be tried.

```
public UITestControl GetPreviousSibling(UITestControl uitc)
{
    UITestControlCollection siblings = uitc.GetParent().GetChildren();
    // Note that 'sibings[0]' has no predecessor
    for (int ii=1; ii<siblings.Count)
    {
        if (uitc.Name == siblings[ii].Name)
        {
            return siblings[ii - 1];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The definition of "sibling" is not clear. This [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vstsqualitytools/2010/04/10/searchconfiguration-nextsibling/) gives some details of siblings.